# Use sed to match any character and carriage return inbetween anyString AND [

Tags: regex, sed

Answer: (slightly modified...) **thanks goes to 0xdeadbeef**:

```
sed -e "s/\t//g" -e "s/(?m)^\s*//g" -e "s/\]\(.\)/]\r\1/g;s/ *\[/[/g;s/\(.\)\[/\1\r[/g" %%~na.txt > %%~na.out
```

I guess I needed to drill down a former question.

I'm using `sed -e`

here's what it does so far

```
sed -e "s/[^[]*/$1/g"
```

it replaces any matching `anyString[` with `$1[`

I'd like to use a regexp variable that holds the value of anyString as `$1` (I used `$1` because that's how powershell held a variable) and reinject it as `$1NEWLINE[`

newline being a newline.

old question:

I have a very specific requirement for data that some people have been helping me with.

I got a script working in powershell using regular expressions, then someone rewrote it, but it still didn't do quite what I needed.

powershell regexp to replace *[ ('any character' 'left bracket'] and replace with *`n[ ('any character' 'new line' 'left bracket')

Somebody else recommended I port it to a linux command line tool. So I opted for sed vs powershell.

We kind of got a working sed script with

```
sed -e "s/^[^[]*//" -e "s/][^\[]*$/]/" -e "s/][^[]*\[/]\n\[/g"
```

but... it has the unwanted behaviour of clearing non [token] data.

Here's the sample input file:

```
item_gloves

[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###
    [ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS]###test###[NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]
###test###[ARMORLEVEL:2]
[UPSTEP:1]
###test###[SHAPED]
[LAYER:ARMOR]###test######test###[COVERAGE:100]###TEST
[LAYER_SIZE:20]
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

Here's what the output should look like

```
item_gloves

[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###
[ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS]
###test###
[NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]
###test###
[ARMORLEVEL:2]
[UPSTEP:1]
###test###
[SHAPED]
[LAYER:ARMOR]
###test######test###
[COVERAGE:100]
###TEST
[LAYER_SIZE:20]
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

I'm thinking I need to borrow some advice from here How to match any non white space character except a particular one?

and use some any character matches to match `anyChar[` and `]anyChar` and insert a new line

anyChar being * respectively.

as well as remove any preceding whitespace

I think I need to match a wildcard

and replace it within something, but I'm missing how to hold the wildcard'd data as a var for the replace `sed -e "s/[^[]*//g"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to:

- remove any spaces after `]`
- insert a newline after `]` if it is followed by a character
- remove any spaces before `[`
- if `[` is preceded by a character, insert a newline before it

As such, you could use the following expression:

```
sed 's/\] */]/g;s/\]\(.\)/]\n\1/g;s/ *\[/[/g;s/\(.\)\[/\1\n[/g' item_gloves
```

This would produce the following output given your sample input:

```
[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###
[ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS]
###test###
[NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]
###test###
[ARMORLEVEL:2]
[UPSTEP:1]
###test###
[SHAPED]
[LAYER:ARMOR]
###test######test###
[COVERAGE:100]
###TEST
[LAYER_SIZE:20]
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

Comment: thank you, and I just truncated all that data due to fear of the question not being accepted!  Your example created an extra carriage return after [armorlevel:2] and before [upstep:1]

Comment: @thistleknot Please do __not__ remove the sample input and expected output from the question.  Could you add it again to the question?

Comment: @thistleknot Regarding _extra carriage return ..._ -- could you tell which version of `sed` are you using?  Are you on Mac or are using BSD `sed`?

Comment: gnuwin32 4.2.1, I ran it like this: sed -e "s/\]\(.\)/]\n\1/g;s/ *\[/[/g;s/\(.\)\[/\1\n[/g" *.txt

Comment: @thistleknot Check the edited answer.  Your input apparently contained lines ending in whitespaces.  The edit should take care of the issue.

Comment: same issue.  I did modify the command to remove any leading/post whitespaces (from prior work, the first -e statement): sed -e "s/(?m)^\s*//g" -e "s/\] */]/g;s/\]\(.\)/]\n\1/g;s/ *\[/[/g;s/\(.\)\[/\1\n[/g"

Comment: @thistleknot I'm not sure what prompted you to post a question if your attempt has to be drastically different from what has been proposed in an answer.  Good luck.

Comment: um... I don't know what you mean by that (removing leading whitespace is part of the answer).  THANK YOU regardless.  Your's is the best working solution atm.  You stated your ver: "remove any spaces before [ " and "remove any spaces after ]", I just swapped IN "-e "s/(?m)^\s*//g"" which replaces any whitespace to include tabs before and after tokens.  Which is fine, because YOUR EXPRESSION is ran just after, they wouldn't conflict at all.  However, even when I just run: sed -e "s/] */]/g;s/](.)/]\n\1/g;s/ *[/[/g;s/(.)[/\1\n[/g" it still has the blank newline that you said was addressed.

Comment: instead of ending with \n[/g I swapped it with \r[/g and it fixed the newline issue :)  Thank you again!.  Full command: sed -e "s/\]\(.\)/]\n\1/g;s/ *\[/[/g;s/\(.\)\[/\1\r[/g" *.txt